# How to identify if login is from Microsoft (personal) account from the JWT claims?

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

In the claims for the JWT token, the PUID value is extracted from the 
*altsecid* claim

```
{
  "aud": "https://graph.windows.net",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/b7-******--5/",
  "iat": 1579684439,
  "nbf": 1579684439,
  "exp": 1579688339,
  "altsecid": "5::10*********E", --> PUID value
  "acr": "1",
  "amr": [
    "pwd",
    "rsa"
  ],
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/b*-**-**-**9/",
  "tid": "b7******---**--****5",
  "unique_name": "abc@xyz",
  "ver": "1.0"
}
```

Points to be noted are: In the case of Microsoft Login the token does not have the object id (oid) claim.
We have custom logic in our code to handle MSA Login from AAD login.

What is the right identifier to establish that a given token is from AAD vs Microsoft Login?

Currently, we have the following logic :

```
if tid == "F8CDEF31-A31E-4B4A-93E4-5F571E91255A" (live.com tenant id)
 OR idp == "live.com"
```

But I want to be sure if I can take a dependency on the altsecid claim as my source of truth for identifying a Microsoft(personal account) Login?

Answer (score 3):

Per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens#payload-claims), you can use either the issuer claim:

> Identifies the security token service (STS) that constructs and returns the token, and the Azure AD tenant in which the user was authenticated. If the token was issued by the v2.0 endpoint, the URI will end in /v2.0. **The GUID that indicates that the user is a consumer user from a Microsoft account is 9188040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad.**

or the tid claim:

> A GUID that represents the Azure AD tenant that the user is from. For work and school accounts, the GUID is the immutable tenant ID of the organization that the user belongs to. For personal accounts, the value is 9188040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad. The profile scope is required to receive this claim.

So Microsoft accounts always have this same tenant ID.
This does not appear to be the one you have though.

I'm not sure why you are looking for this info in an access token meant for Azure AD Graph API though.
You really should not be decoding access tokens not meant for you.
You should look at either the ID token given to your app, or an access token meant for your API.

Comment: Thanks. I exchanged the token for graph audience to be able to talk to AAD(which now also supports Microsoft Login). But in the above token too, oid is missing and from my understanding that happens only in case of Microsoft Login, but it also doesn't match the tid / idp / iss criteria you mentioned from the docs. How do I deal with this token in such case ?

Comment: What authority are you using when authenticating users? `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0` or something else?